# Deploy artifact to Maven repository that has no file extension

Tags: maven, gradle

I want to deploy binary artifacts (Linux and Mac OS X executables) to a Maven repository using Gradle's `MavenPublication` such that they are stored in the repository **without** a file extension (as is the case by default for binaries/executables on Linux and Mac).

Say I have a binary `foo` in version `1.0.0`; in Maven terminology these would be the `artifactId` and `version`, respectively. The closest I can get is to deploy it under the name `foo-1.0.0.` - note the trailing dot (`.`). I would rather want it to be stored under the name `foo-1.0.0` (i.e., without the dot). I tried not specifying the `extension` property, and I also tried specifying an empty `extension=''`.

```
publishing {
  publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
      artifact("some/parent/dir/foo") {
        extension ''
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this? As a related question, what `packaging` should be specified in the POM for such binaries. I've checked [Maven's list of artifact handler types](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.2/maven-core/artifact-handlers.html) but this list does not mention a packaging for binaries, nor those without an extension. I thought about setting it to `binary`, but I'm not sure about consequences this might have.

Answer (score 1):

A Maven repository is the wrong place for this.

Maven repositories work by [Maven coordinates](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) (`groupId`, `artifactId`, `version`), not by file names. The file name is just an internal representation of an artifact with a given set of coordinates.

Comment: If you find it to be the wrong place, what would be a better place then? Quoting from [Maven's Introduction to Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html), "*A repository in Maven holds build artifacts and dependencies of varying types.*". Assume that I made up my mind about what is good or wrong in this case already. Your answer doesn't help either.

Comment: If you really want to use a Maven repository, I would zip the file and store it under type `zip`.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question myself, as far as I have found out, this is currently not possible with Gradle's `MavenPublication`.